# My mesh is a black wireframe but only on layout mode

Tags: mesh, wireframe

[image]

My mesh is black and transparent, only on layout mode and I do not know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The donut is in *wireframe* view, so to make it the default "grey" again, select the sphere in the top right corner of the interface that resembles a filled circle. This will set the object to a "solid" view.

Answer (score 0):

You are in wireframe shading. Switch to solid shading to get it solid grey:

[image]

[image]